# Target id with Tildas

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have an id:

```
#my~~id
```

Q#1: Is there a way to target it using js/jQuery? Ex:

```
var myid = $('#my' + ~~ +'id')
```

Update:  The 'duplicate' doesn't address my question about replace as this question isn't about spaces in a id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first they need to be string and you need to escape them with `\\` as per escaping instructions in [jQuery selectors api](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```
$('#my\\~\\~' +variable)
```

Comment: What about replace?  I tried:  str.replace('my\\~\\~', '');

Comment: you are confusing escaping jquery selector and actual string in replace()

Comment: Oh yes, I see, for replace use single slash to escape each tilda.

Answer (score 0):

In `$` or `querySelector` tilde has a special meaning and won't be interpreted as part of the ID. But `document.getElementById('my~~id')` would allow you to be more specific. Better yet: change to a different ID, this one is hard to work with.